# Remove Left Button from Different View

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, back

Is it possible to run a method in `viewController A` which hides the back button in `viewController B`, but not in `viewController C`?

Example: View A is a "hidden" screen which only initializes a few things for the app. View B is a web view, and View C is a menu. I would like to remove the Back button from View B by calling a method in View A.

Is this possible without implementing the following in the view controller I am trying to load:

```
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this in `viewDidLoad` method of each controller

```
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
```

But if you want to have this done in OOPS way, then make a `baseViewController` & subclass other controllers from `baseViewController`.

Make a method on `baseViewController` as

```
-(void)showBackButton:(Bool)show {

     self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = !show;

}
```

And call this from `viewDidLoad` of your base. This will keep back button to the state represented by "show" value. Then wherever you want it to enable or disable, just call in the viewDidLoad of respective controller.

Hope that helps.